# What determines the bonus you get as a returning Ultimate Team player in Madden 12?

Tags: madden-12

After my first Ultimate Team game in Madden 12, I got a bonus for being a returning player:

- 1000 coins for the games I'd played in previous editions;
- 1000 coins for the games I'd played against the CPU;
- 1000 coins for the total value of my team.

What determines the number of coins you get for each of these experience factors, and are there any others? (I assume there is a credit for games you've played against people.)